# How do I print a set amount of characters corresponding to the value of a variable?

Tags: java, loops, counting

I'm trying to make a system where, someone inputs a number between 0-100, and then the program will allocate the number to a set boundary, basically a grade storing system.
I'll show you my code, then elaborate.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Boundary0/30/40/70 indicates which band the counter is for. e.g. 0-29, 30-39 etc
int Boundary0 = 0;
int Boundary30 = 0;
int Boundary40 = 0;
int Boundary70 = 0;
int Grade;
int count;
count = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//Read in first number
System.out.print("Enter an Integer");
 Grade = in.nextInt();



 while (Grade < 100){    
   //To count number of students
   count++;
   //To allocate each grade to corresponding tier
   if(Grade >= 0 && Grade <= 29){
          Boundary0++;
   }
   if(Grade >= 30 && Grade <= 39){
          Boundary30++;
   }
   if(Grade >= 40 && Grade <= 69){
          Boundary40++;
   }
   if(Grade >= 70 && Grade <= 100){
          Boundary70++;
   }
   Grade = in.nextInt();      
 }

 //To print each boundary seperately with the number of marks in each tier and overall total

    System.out.println("0-29:" + " " + Boundary0 );       
    System.out.println("30-39:" + " " + Boundary30);               
    System.out.println("40-69:" + " "+ Boundary40);        
    System.out.println("70-100:" + " " +Boundary70);        
    System.out.println("Amount of Students: " + count);
}
}
```

As the user inputs a number, the program will add 1 to the corresponding boundary variable

and then when the user inputs a number greater than 100, the program stops and prints the

tiers and beside each tier, tells the user how many values were in each tier.

**So What** I'm trying to do is, at the end of the code, where the sout commands are, to

instead of literally saying how many numbers fell into each section, I want to represent

the value with *s for example

```
0-29: *****
30-39: ****
40-69: ********
70-100: *****
```

Sorry if I'm not being totally clear, I think that may just be a lack of understanding myself...

Thanks

Comment: what do mean by a `*` ?

Comment: So if there were 2 numbers in 30-39, what would the value be?

Comment: Literally just a * for each value that falls in the category, so say there are 5 values entered for a tier, I want 5 stars for the category

Comment: If there were two numbers in 30-30 Boundary30 would equal 2, I'd want two stars to print by the 30-39: at the end

Comment: What is the question? What is your problem with the code you have written?

Comment: How do I do it, where the bold is at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a reusable method that print's `*` for you -

```
public static void printStars(int n){
   for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
     System.out.print("*");
}
```

and call it like this -

```
System.out.println("0-29:" + " " + printStars(Boundary0));
System.out.println("30-39:" + " " + printStars(Boundary30));               
System.out.println("40-69:" + " "+ printStars(Boundary40));        
System.out.println("70-100:" + " " +printStars(Boundary70));
```

Comment: Where would I put that? Sorry, I've literally just started coding

Comment: just put that method next to your main method.

Comment: Awesome :D I've got it working using the reusable method... Great help, And thanks to everyone else for showing me examples to help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Just add additional for-cycles:

```
System.out.print("0-29: ");
for(int i = 0; i < Boundary0; i++){
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: No problem :) but also check Mohammad Adil's answer, which shows you how to reuse this cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already achieved what you desire for with your code.
You just need to print those :

At the end of your code , add following piece :

```
System.out.print("0-29: ");
for(int i=0;i<Boundary0;i++)
{
 System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");

System.out.print("30-39: ");
for(int i=0;i<Boundary30;i++)
{
 System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");

System.out.print("40-69: ");
for(int i=0;i<Boundary40;i++)
{
 System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");

System.out.print("70-100: ");
for(int i=0;i<Boundary70;i++)
{
 System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println("");
```

This would definitely solve the purpose and goes in sync with the code that you have written.

But my personal suggestion would be to use a `HashMap<String,Integer>;` to implement it.

Hope this helps

EDIT!!!

This seems wordy. Try the reusable function for printing '*' in the answer by Mohd. Adil.